# background pattern image on videos having issues while scrolling

Tags: html, css

My code

```
<div id="HomePage"></div>
```

```css
#HomePage {
    background:url('../../images/pattern.png');
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I used video as a background and while scrolling, it creates unwanted horizontal lines across the screen as shown in the screens:

here's the video link. scroll up and down to see that the pattern isn't uniform:
        http://testingprth.hostingsiteforfree.com/demo/

thanks

Comment: Moire effect? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern#Television_screens_and_photographs

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a jsfiddle please? ^ i dont have 50 rep so i have to post this in the answer section ill update it after i take a look

Comment: The problem could be because the browser has to calculate the pixels. There is no way around that, but if the lines are there before scrolling there is def. something wrong with your code. I have seen a solution to the lines by other google employees that did this in some beta testing. What they did was stick the movie inside a canvas using html5, then that canvas inside a positioned relative element inside an absolute element. then when you need to move the video you use the parent element with absolute.

Comment: Very good observation, My motto is: "if the code works in safari, then there must be a solution". It could be a screen display issue but i doubt that because the user might have thrown that into consideration from watching youtube, though there are never any guarantees. I am still waiting to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: looking back at that screenshot, it does look like it could be the quality of the screen.

Comment: Scroll up and down. You will notice the issue. Can't figure out why :(

        http://testingprth.hostingsiteforfree.com/demo/

I have made a replica here. the css file is a bit long but they are all necessary. I have kept the codes minimal possible. 

Thanks guys.